# Is there a way to restrict access to some methods according to the type passed to a generic class?

Tags: c#, generics

I'm currently working on a generic class. I want to restrict accessibility to some methods when passing different types. Let's say it looks something like this:

```
public class MyGeneric<T>
{
public void Foo1(){}
public void Foo2(){}
}
```

I obviously can use the `typeof` operator to implement different behaviours but let's say that Foo1 counts the average of some numbers. If I pass in the type "Student" it can count the average of grades. But let's say I pass in "Car" and I don't want it to do anything. Having it just there and doing nothing with that type would be redundant. Is there a way to completely restrict access to it? Thanks!

Comment: in the code you shared, method `Foo` does not accept any parameters. So where you will pass `Student` or `Car` ? Can you explain the issue with bit more clarity and some more meaningful code?

Comment: [These](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) are all the restrictions you can declare with working with generics.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya by passing a type I meant declaring objects of MyGeneric<T> with different types passed in place of "T".

Comment: You can use constraint feature of Generics where it will restrict you to use only certain type as T. Read [here](https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/csharp/csharp-generic-constraints) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use abstraction/inheritance for this.
Creating a class

```
public class MyGeneric<T>
{
    public void Foo1(){}
}
```

which handles all 'global' functions, and then create a child class like this:

```
public class MyGenericChild<T> : MyGeneric<T> where T : IMyInterface
{
    public void Foo2(){}
}
```

You can then use the specific child to handle the type specific methods.
If needed, you could expand this with a factory-pattern to retreive the correct generic class.